# How to use the google-map-directions element in Polymer?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, polymer

I'm playing around with the designer tool for Polymer. Having followed the standard tutorial that creates a scaffold with a google-map element, and menu items that allow you to switch between satellite or map view, I am now also trying to create another menu item to change to navigation view, using a separate google-map-directions element.

However, after binding the element's map and endAddress properties, it still doesn't do anything.
Here's the code so far:

```
<polymer-element name="my-element">

  <template>
    <style>
       [snipped for brevity]
    </style>
    <core-scaffold id="core_scaffold">
      <core-header-panel mode="seamed" id="core_header_panel" navigation flex>
        <core-toolbar id="core_toolbar">
          <core-field id="core_field" icon="search" theme="core-light-theme" center horizontal layout>
            <core-icon icon="search" id="core_icon"></core-icon>
            <core-input placeholder="text input" inputvalue="Potsdam" value="{{ $.speech_mic.transcript }}" id="core_input" flex></core-input>
            <speech-mic transcript="Potsdam" id="speech_mic"></speech-mic>
          </core-field>
        </core-toolbar>
        <core-menu selected="Roadmap" valueattr="label" selectedindex="0" id="core_menu" theme="core-light-theme">
          <core-item label="Roadmap" icon="star" size="24" id="core_item" on-tap="{{ showRoad }}" horizontal center layout active></core-item>
          <core-item label="Satellite" icon="add-circle-outline" size="24" id="core_item1" on-tap="{{ showSat }}" horizontal center layout></core-item>
          <core-item label="Navigate" icon="settings" size="24" id="navigate" on-tap="{{ showNavigator }}" horizontal center layout></core-item>
        </core-menu>
        <google-map-search map="{{ $.google_map.map }}" query="{{ $.core_input.value }}" id="google_map_search"></google-map-search>
        <google-map-directions map="{{ $.google_map.map }}" endaddress="{{ $.core_input.value }}" travelmode="WALKING" id="google_map_directions"></google-map-directions>
      </core-header-panel>
      <div id="div" tool class="walktitle">Map Test</div>
      <google-map latitude="{{ $.google_map_search.result.latitude }}" longitude="{{ $.google_map_search.result.longitude }}" zoom="18" showcentermarker id="google_map"></google-map>
    </core-scaffold>
  </template>

  <script>

Polymer('my-element', {
      showRoad: function () {
         this.$.google_map.mapType='roadmap'; 
      },
      showSat: function () {
        this.$.google_map.mapType='satellite';
        },
      showNavigator: function (){
        this.$.google_map_directions.route();
      }
    });

  </script>

</polymer-element>
```

It's a bit long, sorry.

There doesn't seem to be any example or documentation out there on this element, just the code.
Anyone know what's missing?

Advice appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There's a PR out for documentation: https://github.com/PolymerLabs/google-map/pull/30

I believe you're missing the `startAddress` on the directions element. The element doesn't activate unless there's a start and end address.

BTW, all three of these elements expose a `map` published property you can bind to:

```
<google-map-search map="{{map}}" ...></google-map-search>
<google-map-directions map="{{map}}" ...></google-map-directions>
<google-map map="{{map}}"></google-map>
```

Consider using that instead of `$.google_map.map` (although that's perfectly fine).

Comment: That's great, thank you!   The $.google_map.map is what the designer put there, but I'll try out the map property instead, thanks for the tip!

Comment: So giving it a random startaddress String (e.g. "Paris") does indeed trigger the navigation properly!  But while I can get the current latitude and longitude via the standard navigator object, how do I hand coordinates to the startaddress attribute? Doesn't seem to work whichever way I try.

Comment: I'm not sure if the element supports that. It's pretty basic right now...startAddress and stopAddress.